# Mongo running slow on Amazon EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been using compose.io to host my Mongo instance. My data is getting bigger and its becoming cost prohibitive to stay there so I'd like to move to EC2 where I have ~$750 in credits.

**The problem:**

I have an endpoint to authenticate a user that I run from my localhost:

When my API is pointed at the compose.io database its ~200ms response time

When my API is pointed at my new EC2 Mongo instances its ~700ms response time.

(The databases are exact copies)

Pinging the EC2 instance is ~90-100ms.

The collections have been reIndexed() and there is zero load on the Mongo instance.

**Details on the EC2 instance:**

M3.large

100 Provision iOPs

Zero traffic /load.

I cannot figure out why Mongo is just so slow to respond. When I authenticate several things occur against the database (Here is the output from mongod.log)

```
2015-11-22T13:44:15.631+0000 [conn6] insert production.transactions query: { method: "POST", resource: "/api/v1.1/login", body: { password: "***********", email: "********" }, timezone: "America/New_York", agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36", _id: ObjectId('5651c6afdc24948b9f2e15e5'), created: new Date(1448199855577), __v: 0 } ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:99 0ms
2015-11-22T13:44:15.631+0000 [conn6] command production.$cmd command: insert { insert: "transactions", documents: [ { method: "POST", resource: "/api/v1.1/login", body: { password: "***********", email: "*******" }, timezone: "America/New_York", agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36", _id: ObjectId('5651c6afdc24948b9f2e15e5'), created: new Date(1448199855577), __v: 0 } ], ordered: false, writeConcern: { w: 1 } } keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:83 reslen:40 0ms
2015-11-22T13:44:15.734+0000 [conn8] query production.users query: { email: "*******" } planSummary: IXSCAN { email: 1 } ntoskip:0 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) r:125 nreturned:1 reslen:1553 0ms
2015-11-22T13:44:15.918+0000 [conn7] remove production.tokens query: { user_id: "5330d44ba6885a020005bc88" } ndeleted:0 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:236 0ms
2015-11-22T13:44:15.918+0000 [conn7] command production.$cmd command: delete { delete: "tokens", deletes: [ { q: { user_id: "5330d44ba6885a020005bc88" }, limit: 0 } ], ordered: true, writeConcern: { w: 1 } } keyUpdates:0 numYields:0  reslen:40 0ms
2015-11-22T13:44:16.019+0000 [conn9] insert production.tokens query: { _id: "Tor9ke2lrt5Ooeifuh6hnCYFmmpDlWu8tRu2T2uZbgylFpx8EBlg1Aw7cQKQNc0I09zRhLrxdceV7lTf6UWl769ZMLX1cxlb0qksY8ssj1zme9uT1PkpNlIlNdBJE40S", user_id: "5330d44ba6885a020005bc88", expires: new Date(1448804120000), created: new Date(1448199855964), __v: 0 } ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:73 0ms
2015-11-22T13:44:16.020+0000 [conn9] command production.$cmd command: insert { insert: "tokens", documents: [ { _id: "Tor9ke2lrt5Ooeifuh6hnCYFmmpDlWu8tRu2T2uZbgylFpx8EBlg1Aw7cQKQNc0I09zRhLrxdceV7lTf6UWl769ZMLX1cxlb0qksY8ssj1zme9uT1PkpNlIlNdBJE40S", user_id: "5330d44ba6885a020005bc88", expires: new Date(1448804120000), created: new Date(1448199855964), __v: 0 } ], ordered: false, writeConcern: { w: 1 } } keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:105 reslen:40 0ms
2015-11-22T13:44:16.128+0000 [conn10] command production.$cmd command: findAndModify { findandmodify: "users", query: { _id: ObjectId('5330d44ba6885a020005bc88') }, new: false, remove: false, upsert: false, update: { $set: { last_login: new Date(1448199856068) } }, writeConcern: { w: 1 } } update: { $set: { last_login: new Date(1448199856068) } } nscanned:1 nscannedObjects:1 nMatched:1 nModified:1 fastmod:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:130 reslen:1624 0ms
```

Comment: There is more information that we need to troubleshoot the issue, what kind of workload are you doing reading? writing? or balanced between both? Does your data fit in memory or is it always hitting the disk? Are you actually reaching the provisioned IO cap?

Comment: 1. work load is low, it is only me issuing this request. This single request as you can see does some reads and writes. Data fits in memory entire database is < 1gig and the instance has 15gig memory. I can't be reaching the provisioned IO cap as its only me issuing this one POST request which triggers those ~5 queries.

Comment: Are the latency times directly to mongo? or are you passing through an application? If you are using an application, is it hosted at the same region as your mongo instance?

Comment: The latency I am experiencing is the same if I access the database via my Heroku app, or if I access it via my machine (localhost). I wanted to rule out network latency which is why I pinged it and I see 90-100ms response from ping

Comment: I forgot to add the compose.io instance is a 2 member replica set, my EC2 is a single mongo instance if that matters

Comment: Replica doesn't really improve performance all that much, its primary purpose is fail over, all the writes go to the primary no matter what. If I understand this correctly, you have 100ms latency between your application instance and mongo? If that is the case, then every single query/command you do on mongo will add 100ms latency to your api endpoint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95861/discussion-between-nwkeeley-and-datasage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the issue appears to be setting up a mongo instance in US west while hosting the application in US East. Network latency is the cause of the increased response time.

Comment: Yup this was exactly it. Heroku + Compose.io both run in US East, my EC2 instance was in US West. Moving it to US East resolved the issue.